# Are derivatives of the standard Gaussian density bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, derivatives, normal-distribution, hermite-polynomials

Suppose that $\varphi$ is the density of the standard Gaussian distribution given by
$$
\varphi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-x^2/2)
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb R$. The derivatives of $\varphi$ are given by the formula
$$
\varphi^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n\mathit{He}_n(x)\varphi(x)
$$
for each $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\ge0$, where $\mathit{He}_n$ is the $n$-th probabilists' [Hermite polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials).

It is straightforward to see that $\varphi$ and its first two derivatives are bounded. We have that
\begin{align*}
|\phi(x)|&\le (2\pi)^{-1/2}\approx0.399\\
|\varphi'(x)|&\le\varphi(1)\approx0.242\\
|\varphi''(x)|&\le (2\pi)^{-1/2}\approx0.399
\end{align*}
for each $x\in\mathbb R$.

> Does there exist $c>0$ such that $|\varphi^{(n)}(x)|\le c$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\ge0$? If not, are all derivatives of $\varphi$ bounded, i.e. does there exist a positive sequence $c_n$ such that $|\varphi^{(n)}(x)|\le c_n$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$ and $n\ge0$?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Note that the Hermite-polynomials form an orthogonal basis w.r.t. the weight $\exp(-x^2/2)$. This means their square is integrable, which (assuming no strange oscillations) will tell you something about its behaviour towards infinity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each individual $\varphi^{(n)}(x)$ is bounded, simply because it is a continuous function tending to zero at infinity.

However, we can't find a $c$ that uniformly bounds the entire sequence. To see this, just write down the Taylor series for $\varphi$:
$$ \varphi (x) = \exp(-x^2)= 1 - x^2 + \frac 1 {2!} x^4 - \frac 1 {3!} x^6 + \dots$$
[I dropped some constant factors to keep the notation simple.]

Differentiating, and evaluating at $x = 0$ for even $n$ (say $n = 2m$), we see that
$$ |\varphi^{(2m)}( 0)| = \frac{(2m)!}{m!},$$
which tends to infinity as $m \to \infty$.

I plotted up to four derivatives of the function on Mathematica. You can see that the peaks of these functions grow pretty fast!

[image]